# How to change multiple page/blocks Store View?

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view

I created a new Store View in my Magento 1.9.1.0 and now I need to set some of my pages and blocks to "All Store Views".

When I go to `CMS > Page` or `CMS > Static Blocks` I am able to open **one** item (page or block) and change the Store View inside it. Do I need to do it manually for each page/block or is there an easy way to do that? (Like multiple select changes)

Thanks!

Comment: Their is no easy way to do that you need lots of customization to add and use mass action, however their is a extension available that will provide option to update store by selecting multiple blocks in grid. http://www.nextbits.eu/magento-enhanced-improved-cms-extension.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run sql to update them by batch,

1. Mark down all your cms page id that want to switch to all store view
2. insert record into table 'cms_page_store', where the page id is the cms you mentioned in step1, set store_id = 0 (means all store view)

Comment: Thanks @leo, just a small fix in your answer: If I already have the pages, I will need to **modify** the record instead of insert a duplicated one, right?

Comment: Anyway, thanks for giving the directions to the right table :)

Comment: Yes, you dont need to copy the page "content" into a new record, only associate it to another store_id. You can observe  what data is updated 'cms_page_store'  when you save a page in magento admin. It helps you to know how to write your query.